# Concat() alternate group by python3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My goal here is to concat() alternate groups between two dataframe.

desired result :

```
 group  ordercode   quantity
0  A            1
    B           1
    C       1
    D          1
0   A          1
    B           3       

1   A           1
    B           2
    C           1
1  A        1
    B           1
    C           2
```

My dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame([[0,"A",1],[0,"B",1],[0,"C",1],[0,"D",1],[1,"A",1],[1,"B",2],[1,"C",1]],columns=["group","ordercode","quantity"])
df2=pd.DataFrame([[0,"A",1],[0,"B",3],[1,"A",1],[1,"B",1],[1,"C",2]],columns=["group","ordercode","quantity"])
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

I have used `dfff=pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index(kind="merge")`

but I have got the below result:

```
    group   ordercode   quantity
0   0   A   1
0   0   A   1
1       B   1
1       B   3
2       C   1
3       D   1
4   1   A   1
4   1   A   1
5       B   2
5       B   1
6       C   1
6       C   2
```

You can see here the concatenate is formed between each rows not by group.
It has to print like

`group 0 of df1`
`group0 of df2`
`group1 of df1`
`group1 of df2` and `so on`

Note:
  I have created these DataFrame using `groupby()` function

```
  df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.apply(lambda x: [x[0]] * x[1], 1).as_matrix()), 
              columns=['ordercode'])
df['quantity'] = 1
df['group'] = sorted(list(range(0, len(df)//3, 1)) * 4)[0:len(df)]


df=df.groupby(['group', 'ordercode']).sum()
```

Question:

Where I went wrong?
Its sorting out by taking `index`

I have used `.set_index("group")` but It didnt work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for helper column used for sorting by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) :

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('ordercode').cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('ordercode').cumcount()

dfff = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values(['group','g']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (dfff)
    group ordercode  quantity  g
0       0         A         1  0
1       0         B         1  0
2       0         C         1  0
3       0         D         1  0
4       0         A         1  0
5       0         B         3  0
6       1         C         2  0
7       1         A         1  1
8       1         B         2  1
9       1         C         1  1
10      1         A         1  1
11      1         B         1  1
```

and last remove column:

```
dfff = dfff.drop('g', axis=1)
```

Comment: Not sure if understand, `df1['g'] = df1.groupby('ordercode').cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('ordercode').cumcount()` code create new columns `g` in both DataFrames. So it should working.

Comment: I alos add `.reset_index(drop=True)` now for avoid duplicates index values.

Comment: @i1100362 - Super ;)